# Apache Beam Python DoFn process method and keyword arguments

Tags: python, parameter-passing, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam SDK 2.43.0 with Python 3.8 and I am seeing some behaviour in the example below that I do not understand.

If I run the snippet as given, I get the error:

```
  ...
  File "apache_beam\runners\common.py", line 983, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
TypeError: process() got multiple values for argument 'some_side_input' [while running 'use side input']
```

If I use `beam.ParDo(UseSideInput(), beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar))` instead of `beam.ParDo(UseSideInput(), some_side_input=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar))`, i.e. use a positional argument for the `some_side_input` parameter instead of a keyword argument, the pipeline runs as expected.

Similarly, if I use the `UseSideInputNoTimestamp` DoFn, which does not have the `timestamp` parameter in the `process` method, the pipeline runs and allows `some_side_input` to be supplied as a keyword argument.

Another option is to specify the `process` method as `process(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, some_side_input=None)` and the snippet runs as is allowing a keyword argument. But, I am then providing a default value just to allow for the keyword argument.

Just wondering, is this error expected and if so what is the reason for it?

```py
import apache_beam as beam
import time


class UseSideInput(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, some_side_input, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
        yield f"{element}~{some_side_input}~{timestamp.to_rfc3339()}"


class UseSideInputNoTimestamp(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, some_side_input):
        yield f"{element}~{some_side_input}"


with beam.Pipeline() as p:

    pcollect_bar = p | "create bar" >> beam.Create(["bar"])

    (
        p
        | "create foo" >> beam.Create(["foo"])
        | "add timestamp" >> beam.Map(lambda element: beam.window.TimestampedValue(element, int(time.time())))
        # | "use side input" >> beam.ParDo(UseSideInput(), beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar)) <-- works
        # | "use side input no ts" >> beam.ParDo(UseSideInputNoTimestamp(),
        #                                        some_side_input=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar)) <-- works
        | "use side input" >> beam.ParDo(UseSideInput(), some_side_input=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar))
        | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I understood, the behaviour is if you have only the side input parameter, you can pass it with a keyword argument or positional argument,  but if you have multiple parameters, you have to use positional arguments :

- Only side input argument :

```py
def test_side_input(self):
        import apache_beam as beam
        import time
        

        class UseSideInput(beam.DoFn):
            def process(self, element, some_side_input, *args, **kwargs):
                yield f"{element}~{some_side_input}"

        with beam.Pipeline() as p:
            pcollect_bar = p | "create bar" >> beam.Create(["bar"])

            (
                    p
                    | "create foo" >> beam.Create(["foo"])
                    | "add timestamp" >> beam.Map(
                lambda element: beam.window.TimestampedValue(element, int(time.time())))
                    | "use side input one arg positional" >> beam.ParDo(UseSideInput(), beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar))
                    # | "use side input one arg param" >> beam.ParDo(UseSideInput(),
                    #                                        some_side_input=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar))
                    | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
            )
```

- Multiple arguments :

```py
def test_side_input(self):
        import apache_beam as beam
        import time

        class UseSideInput(beam.DoFn):
            def process(self, element, some_side_input, other, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, *args, **kwargs):
                yield f"{element}~{some_side_input}~{timestamp.to_rfc3339()}"

        with beam.Pipeline() as p:
            pcollect_bar = p | "create bar" >> beam.Create(["bar"])

            (
                    p
                    | "create foo" >> beam.Create(["foo"])
                    | "add timestamp" >> beam.Map(
                lambda element: beam.window.TimestampedValue(element, int(time.time())))
                    | "use side input" >> beam.ParDo(UseSideInput(),
                                                     beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar),
                                                     0)
                    | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
            )
```

In the second example, I have 2 arguments : `some_side_input` and `other`

According to the [documentation : 4.5.3. Accessing additional parameters in your DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs), the timestamp allows to access to the timestamp of element and needs to have a default value with `beam.DoFn.TimestampParam` :

```py
import apache_beam as beam

class ProcessRecord(beam.DoFn):

  def process(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
     # access timestamp of element.
     pass
```

This `timestamp` argument is not considered like other usual arguments.

You also have an alternative for side inputs and use methods as functions in `Map` or `FlatMap` (built in `Beam` `DoFn`) and in this case the keyword arguments works everytime :

```py
def test_other(self):
        import apache_beam as beam
        import time

        def to_element(element, some_side_input, other):
            return f"{element}~{some_side_input}~{other}"

        with beam.Pipeline() as p:
            pcollect_bar = p | "create bar" >> beam.Create(["bar"])

            (
                    p
                    | "create foo" >> beam.Create(["foo"])
                    | "add timestamp" >> beam.Map(
                lambda element: beam.window.TimestampedValue(element, int(time.time())))
                    | "use side input" >> beam.Map(to_element,
                                                   some_side_input=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(pcollect_bar),
                                                   other=0)
                    | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
            )
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really answer the question that I had. My main question is why do I get the error shown when I run the snippet I provided as it is i.e. I get `TypeError: process() got multiple values for argument 'some_side_input' [while running 'use side input']` just because I make the call using a keyword argument for `some_side_input`.

Comment: In this case you have a second argument that is timestamp, in this case you can’t pass the side input param with keyword argument, you have to pass it with positional argument

Comment: Timestamp needs having a default value according to the documentation